# Почему не отображается полностью ListView?

Tags: android, xml, listview

Имею следующую разметку экрана `basket_fragment.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/basket_fragment_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`RecyclerView` содержит в себе `CardView` которые в сво. очередь задаются таким образом basket_card_view.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/basket_fragment_card_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  <!--this 200 dp!-->>
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_fragment_card_view_text_view_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recipe Name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/basket_fragment_card_view_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/basket_fragment_card_view_text_view_title"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Проблема в том, что отображается только один элемент из списка `ListView`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Если определить строго размер `CardView`, например `android:layout_height="200dp"`, то элементы списка отображаются (на ту доступную высоту, сколько возможно).

Как избавиться от данной проблемы и сделать так что бы размер карточки (`CardView`) зависел от внутреннего заполнения (`wrap_content`) с учетом количества элементов?

**UPD**. Возможно я не прав в плане выбора виджета для отображения списка строк с чекбоксами (то есть в данном случае, например, рациональней было бы использовать динамическое добавление элементов в, например, какой нибудь LinearLayout в самом коде), но мне все равно немного не ясна проблема

Comment: проблема в том что у вас листвью кладется в recyclerview. избавтесь от этого

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я несколько изменил отображение, заменил ListView на LinearLayout (vertical), определил новый xml отвечающий за нужное мне отображение (строка с чекбоксом), и динамически в коде, в for-each цикле создаю (inflate) и добавляю в контейнер (тот что LinearLaout) отображения. Но вопрос - на сколько это разумно и грамотно со стороны разработки? Хотелось бы делать по мимо рабочего кода, так же качественный и понятный

Comment: Думается, что Вы какой-то костыль изобретаете. Для чего вы циклом пытаетесь ваш лэйаут наполнить? Ведь для такой цели у вас имеется RecyclerView, который по всей видимости пока что простаивается=) Вам надо написать лишь адаптер для него и загнать list с вашими объектами.

Comment: Замените ListView на RecyclerView, он будет корректно растягивать ваши CardView. @АндроидАндроид речь идет о вложенном списке в каждый элемент RecyclerView

Comment: @АндроидАндроид возможно. Но возможно я не верно описал строение экрана. Фрагмент содержит Recycler, он в свою очередь содержит некое множество CardView, он же в свою очередь содержит еще элементы и один из них - как раз таки статичный (для каждого CardView свой) список, который я и определил как LinearLayout. В фрагменте я переопределил Adapter и ViewHolder который работает к карточками, и как раз в одном из методов ViewHolder'a я и заполняю данными список в карточках. Вы предлагаете этот список (в моем случае LinearLayout) заменить на еще один RecyclerView со своим адаптером и вьюхолдером?

Comment: @mamba0767 нет нет нет, это просто я неправильно понял

Comment: @АндроидАндроид я могу дополнить свой ответ решением, для того что бы Вы прокомментировали правильность или неправльность решения с вашей точки зрения? Я проблему уже решил, но хотелось бы ее решить все таки качественно.

Comment: @mamba0767 Так, конечно выкладывайте, помимо меня тут есть другие пользователи, которые тоже могут помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом - заменил `ListView` вложенный в каждый `CardView`на `LinearLayout`, своеобразный контейнер который должен содержать нужные мне отображения каждого элемента, который я добавляю динамически в коде, во время отрисовки каждого элемента `CardView` из `RecyclerView`. Вот так теперь выглядит метод `onBindRecipeViewHolder` в `ViewHolder` для моего `RecyclerView`, который вызывается в `Adapter` в методе `onBindViewHolder`

```
public void onBindRecipeViewHolder(Recipe recipe) {
            recipeTitle.setText(recipe.getTitle());
            elementList = RecipeElementLab.get(getActivity()).getRecipeElements(recipe.getId().toString());

            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "elements = " + elementList);

            for (RecipeElement elem: elementList) {
                LinearLayout anotherElementLL = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                        .inflate(R.layout.basket_card_view_element_item, null);
                anotherElementLL.setId(View.generateViewId());

                container.addView(anotherElementLL);

                TextView elemName = (TextView) anotherElementLL.findViewById(R.id.basket_fragment_card_view_layout_text_view_ingr_name);
                elemName.setText(elem.getName() + " / " + elem.getCount());
            }
        }
```

И выглядит теперь все корректно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен, если сможете посоветовать более корректный способ достичь данного результата, так как гложет ощущение, что данный способ не самый корректный

Comment: Вполне рабочее решение, только я вам рекомендую вынести инфлейт контейнера и `findViewById()` из цикла. Это очень ресурсоемкие операции, а вы их выполняете для каждого элемента в цикле, хотя их результат за время выполнения цикла не изменяется.

Comment: @pavlofff я может не правильно вас понял, но сам контейнер у меня раздувается один раз, а в цикле раздуваются "маленькие" LinearLayout содержащие строку и чекбокс и добавляются в контейнер. Или вы имеете ввиду что объекту, который я назвал anotherElementLL, в цикле назначать каждый раз только id и после уже добавлять с новым id?

Comment: Да, конечно. инфлейт `anotherElementLL` и получение ссылки на `elemName` нужно вынести из цикла - создавать эти объекты перед тем, как начнется заполнение и использовать один и тот же объект для всех элементов в цикле. Это слишком "дорогие" операции, чтобы выполнять их каждый раз впустую. Кроме того, если вы не используете нигде ID для `anotherElementLL` (в коде этого не видно), то и его назначать нет никакой необходимости, ID контейнеру нужен, только если вы желаете обращаться именно к нему (а не вложенным в него виджетам) из кода.

Comment: Проблема будет, когда надо будет отлавливать нажатия на галки и обновлять данные. Все будет скакать при обновлении.